# Move custom popup up when keyboard is showing in android

Tags: android

My popup layout extending relative layout. In popup i placed edittext. I am displaying popup with arrow based on view. I want to move only popup when keyboard is showing. 
Please help me, how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

To the relevant activity in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

> "adjustResize" - The activity's main window is always resized to make
>   room for the soft keyboard on screen.